# How to change a table key - LUA langg

Tags: lua

How to change a table key?

Example:
`local tab01 = {["key_x"] = "xx", ["key_y"] = "yy"}`

1) How to change the "key_x" key to a "key_x2" key?

2) If not, how to implement a dictionary that allows changing the key?

Answer (score 3):

There's not an atomic way to do it, so just do it in 2 steps:

```
tab01.key_x2 = tab01.key_x
tab01.key_x = nil
```

Since Lua doesn't have preemptive multithreading, this shouldn't be a problem.